# upgrade to iOS 6.1.2 sdk available?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I recently updated my iphone to 6.1.2.. I am no longer able to use my iphone for development as i have the ios 6 sdk! What should i do now? Should i upgrade my ios sdk to 6.1.2?**Is it available??**.. I was looking to do that but all i could find was several beta versions of ios 6  sdk which clearly don't specify what version they are in the apple developer site??

I tried to upgrade my ios sdk from XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads .. But apparently there isn't any update to the ios sdk 6.1.2 available there!

Any suggestions on how i can resolve this issue?
Help is greatly appreciated.Thank you!!

Comment: You need Xcode 4.6.x to used iOS 6.1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your Xcode to support your Iphone's os version... You can easily upgrade your Xcode from AppStore in your mac..... 
Just click App Store and then see the update tab... you will got what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The latest Xcode (Get it from the Mac App Store) should give you everything you need!

Answer (score 0):

Go on [iOS dev center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action), and download last XCode 4.6.1 (which includes the latest SDK 6.1) directly.